# Need help on Mongo Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

We have the below data:

```
[
{
    "location" : {
            "type" : "POINT",
            "coordinates" : [
                -92.41151,
                35.11683
            ]
    },
    "geoHash" : "dr72jwgnbbst"
},
{
    "location" : {
            "type" : "POINT",
            "coordinates" : [
                -89.58342,
                36.859161
            ]
    },
    "geoHash" : "dn6qtkr5xk8m"
},
{
    "location" : {
            "type" : "POINT",
            "coordinates" : [
                -86.038762,
                36.519016
            ]
    },
    "geoHash" : "dn6zf0h6xtcp"
},
{
    "location" : {
            "type" : "POINT",
            "coordinates" : [
                -98.3081936,
                26.2143207
            ]
    },
    "geoHash" : "9udj4unjmp9f"
},
{
    "location" : {
            "type" : "POINT",
            "coordinates" : [
                -98.5377275,
                29.4878928
            ]
    },
    "geoHash" : "9v1zv8p52t8u"
},
{
    "location" : {
            "type" : "POINT",
            "coordinates" : [
                -73.7018126,
                42.641387
            ]
    },
    "geoHash" : "dreddfeup69m"
},
{
    "location" : {
            "type" : "POINT",
            "coordinates" : [
                -111.865295,
                33.431942
            ]
    },
    "geoHash" : "9tbqnqn5jtwq"
},
{
    "location" : {
            "type" : "POINT",
            "coordinates" : [
                -79.810763,
                34.174603
            ]
    },
    "geoHash" : "dnp4rv796rtz"
}]
```

We need a query to get the locations for the geohashes which start with "dn", "9t", "dr", "9v", "9u" and only one location per that geo hash should be returned. for ex, we have 3 locations whose geohash starts with "dn", but it should only return any one location.
Output:

```
"dr" -> "location" : {
        "type" : "POINT",
        "coordinates" : [
            -92.41151,
            35.11683
        ]
    }
"dn" ->     "location" : {
        "type" : "POINT",
        "coordinates" : [
            -89.58342,
            36.859161
        ]
    }
"9u" ->     "location" : {
        "type" : "POINT",
        "coordinates" : [
            -98.3081936,
            26.2143207
        ]
    }
"9v" -> "location" : {
        "type" : "POINT",
        "coordinates" : [
            -98.5377275,
            29.4878928
        ]
    }
"9t" ->     "location" : {
        "type" : "POINT",
        "coordinates" : [
            -111.865295,
            33.431942
        ]
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always check for first two characters of `geoHash` then try bebow query:

```js
db.locations.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            geoHash: {
                $regex: '^dn|^9t|^dr|^9v|^9u',
                $options: 'i'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            geoHashSubStr: {
                $substr: ["$geoHash", 0, 2]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$geoHashSubStr",
            // Group other fields based on your requirement.
            location: {
                $first: "$location"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

1. Group all results by the first 2 characters of `geoHash`.
2. Project only the first element of that array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $substr: [
          "$geoHash",
          0,
          2
        ]
      },
      locations: {
        $push: "$location"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: true,
      location: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$locations",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/C_Jh5cPtldd